# 'Duped' again...is that a "real word"?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

My question, titled [what does the phrase "a real word" mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/268623/what-does-the-phrase-a-real-word-mean), from Sept 2015 has been closed as a duplicate of [What are the criteria to adopt new words into English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11455/what-are-the-criteria-to-adopt-new-words-into-english), from Feb 2011.

Aside from the suspect timing, with more than a year lag between the asking and the determination that my question was a duplicate, my question asks about the meaning of a phrase ("real word"), while the proposed duplicate asks, reflexively, what the criteria are for adopting (existing?) words into English.

There doesn't seem to be a legitimate intersection between the two queries. The same ground isn't covered in the answers; the two questions are disparate.

Is this more careless duping? Why, and how, did it come up so long after the fact of the asking?

Comment: Its first close vote was on October 7 which put it into the Close review queue, where it received the [other four votes](http://english.stackexchange.com/review/close/203319). It is notable that the first sentence is *I'm interested in how a word becomes "a real word" in English, and what constitutes that "real word" when it exists,* which would seem quite a good fit to the duplicate. That sentence doesn't mean "What is a real word when it's at home?" to me. I'm sure the question could be made clearer without invalidating the answers which answer the question you meant to ask.

Comment: A fair point. I'll just delete that first sentence. It's not really necessary.

Comment: I remember I was a little reluctant to click the skip button when I review the question. Wouldn't "What are the criteria to adopt new **real** words into English?" answer your question? As one of the comments suggests, your question reads more like a philosophical one as it is not that easy to define the word "real". I think the answers posted to your question are not very different from those to the dupe master. Anything that I am missing? It might not appear duplicate to you as an asker, but I don't think it is careless duping.

Comment: (transferred my original comment on the main to here) Why was the answer which was awarded a bounty, deleted by a mod? Did you request it yourself?

Comment: Did you not receive a notification from the system  when your question was closed? No... and OPs aren't notified when their questions are closed as duplicates, are they? I'm sure there was a recent question on meta about this issue.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, another participant here discovered that the accepted, bounty answer was first used at another site, and flagged the answer. As you say, I wasn't notified that the question was duped. I found out when the poster who flagged the borrowed answer notified me that he had done so. It does seem that OP's should be notified when a question is closed, for whatever reason.

Comment: So why not just add the original source instead of deleting it? Unless of course you no longer find it helpful.

Comment: @Rathony, I think I pointed out in the question that "is X a word" is used as the equivalent of "is X a real word".

Comment: It's *pure* plagiarism, I thought you meant that the answer had been posted elsewhere on SE. The original post (*I think*) comes from here: http://fandom-grammar.livejournal.com/48852.html (dated: 2010)

Comment: @Mari-LouA, I think the answer was borrowed wholesale, and was one of several such by the same poster here. I haven't investigated the issue myself, and didn't delete the answer (but did agree with the deletion in the circumstances). I do wonder why the bounty wasn't restarted when the answer it was awarded to was deleted.

Comment: @JEL Yes, you are assuming there's got to be some differences between "word" and "real word". Is there any word that is not real? I am not sure. That's my point.

Comment: @Rathony, I realize the question is, of necessity, confusing, but my assumption was the opposite: there is no functional difference between 'word' and 'real word'. The only difference is ornamental.